# Is it possible to add a link in the validation rule of a unique email?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my Model:

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    return $rules->add($rules->isUnique(
        ['email'], 
        "This email is already registered on the site. If it's yours, then you can restore access by clicking on the link <a href='#'>Restore access</a> and follow the instructions."
    ));
}
```

Can I somehow cancel the escaping for the link?

Somehow, by type: 'escape' => false in View ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable error messages escaping, you need to specify escape => false in error options in `FormHelper::control()`:

```
<?=
$this->Form->control("email", [
    "label" => "Your email",
    "error" => [
        "escape" => false
    ]
])
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Szymon